# GPU Bitxor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gpu

```
gx = gpuArray(uint8(X));
gtm = gpuArray(uint8(tm));
gx = arrayfun(bitxor,gtm,gx);
```

Error:

```
Error using ==> bitxor
Not enough input arguments.

Error in ==> Encryption at 57
gx = arrayfun(bitxor,gtm,gx);
```

I get the above Error If I try to execute the code. Someone Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `arrayfun` must be a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html), like so:

```
gx = arrayfun( @bitxor, gtm, gx );
```

The error message you're getting is because you've asked MATLAB to execute `bitxor` with no input arguments, and pass the result as the first argument to `arrayfun`.

In this case, you don't need the `arrayfun` call at all, and can simply execute

```
gx = bitxor( gtm, gx );
```